Tanker Losing Water while Moving down a Valley
I'm studying for the IPhO, and came across this question.

Now, initially I thought of the following situation; at any instant, a water droplet would have to acquire the same instantaneous velocity as the tanker at the instant it was released.
This is because relative to the tanker, the water droplet would have $\vec0$ velocity at the instant when it is just being dropped.
If the mass of the tanker was $M$ and the mass of the $n$th water droplet was $m_n$, initially, before any water fell out, the total kinetic energy was:
$$\frac{1}{2}Mu^2+\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2}m_iu^2$$
However, after this I got stuck since I felt that mechanical energy conservation might not work here.
Due to the droplets of water falling, there would be a thrust force on the tank, which would reduce its velocity, and prevent us from conserving total mechanical energy.
All I could conclude is that, if the initial potential energy of the tanker was $Mgh_1$ and the final potential energy was $(M-\sum{m}_i)gh_2$, in the absence of a thrust force,
$$h_2=\frac{M}{M-\sum{m}_i}h_1$$
So if we were to consider the thrust force,
$h_2<\frac{M}{M-\sum{m}_i}h_1$.
But I realized this approach does not allow me to comment on whether $h_1>h_2$, $h_1=h_2$ or $h_1<h_2$.
Is there any way I could proceed from here, or anything that I'm missing out?
PS: The actual answer given was that $h_1=h_2$, but I can't think of a way to logically prove this.
The hint given was that the speed of the water droplets must be equal to that of the tanker at the instant of their release, but I had already considered this in my logic, and I could not proceed further.

I wasn't absolutely positive, but the given answer agrees with my initial guess and I might work it out later.  In the mean time, I have a comment based on gut reaction.  Think of problems where you calculate height based on initial KE and final PE -- the mass always cancels out.  Might be easier to think in terms of some portion of the mass being dumped in one discrete event.
